# Why can't I match POSIX Character Classes

Tags: .net, regex, posix

The following snippet prints `False`:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abc", @"[[:alpha:]]"));
```

But this prints `True`:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abc", @"[a-zA-Z]"));
```

Why? Shouldn't they be equivalent?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that .NET's regular expression language supports POSIX character classes? I think it only supports Unicode named categories/blocks.

Comment: @Gabe—I did, but only cause I read something wrong! Also a few questions I saw here on SO tagged `.NET` were answered with POSIX character classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

.NET Regexes don't support the Posix character classes. They do however support Unicode groups.

This would work:

`Regex.IsMatch("abc", @"^\p{L}+$");`

The `\p{L}` group matches all Unicode letters.

See here for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CategoryOrBlock

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories for the list of acceptable categories and blocks.

Comment: Unfortunately Unicode category `L` does not correspond to all letters. This is why Unicode `PropList.txt` defines the `Other_Alphabetic` property, which, together with the `L` category and `Nl`, makes up the `Alphabetic` property in `DerivedCoreProperties.txt`. An application almost always needs to know of a character has the `Alphabetic` property, not category `L`. Unfortunately you won't notice the difference until one of your users whose language uses a non-Latin alphabet complains, long after your broken application is deployed... :-(