# RegEx - Text between two markers with one of them optional

Tags: c#, regex, string

Using RegEx, Is there a way to extract all the text between 2 marker where the 2nd marker is optional?

**For example:**

```
MARK1 allthetext I need t0 extr4ct i$ here unt.l I_will-find (MARK2 | MARK3 | ANYENDMARK)
```

or

```
MARK1 allthetext I need t0 extr4ct i$ here unt.l I_will-find nothing else
```

---

I tryed to use

```
(?<=(MARK1 ))([[:ascii:]]*)(MARK2|MARK3|$)?
```

and

```
(?<=(MARK1 ))([[:ascii:]]*)(?=(MARK2|MARK3|$))?
```

without success.

---

PS: I need to evalute the regex in C#. I'm using regex101.com as test environment

Comment: The beginning mark isn't optional?

Comment: Try [`(?<=\bMARK1\b)(.*?)(?=(?:\bMARK2\b|\bMARK3\b|$))`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cbMARK1%5cb)(.*%3f)(%3f%3d(%3f%3a%5cbMARK2%5cb%7c%5cbMARK3%5cb%7c%24))&i=MARK1+allthetext+I+need+t0+extr4ct+i%24+here+unt.l+I_will-find+(MARK2+%7c+MARK3+%7c+ANYENDMARK)%0d%0a%0d%0aMARK1+allthetext+I+need+t0+extr4ct+i%24+here+unt.l+I_will-find+nothing+else&o=s). I do not believe C# supports any POSIX classes.

Comment: @stribizhev gothca! It seems to work weel. I didn't know about the propert meaning of \b. Thank you, post it as a reply

Comment: @Riccardo: Please check my answer. And note that you should not test .NET regex on regex101.com. Use regexhero.net or regexstorm.net. The latter provides sharing, that is why I am using it for demo purposes.

Comment: @stribizhev many thanks for the clear reply and suggestions about regex101.com and the other sites. I had to wait a bunch of minutes before mark your answer as the chosen one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=\bMARK1\b)(.*?)(?=(?:\bMARK2\b|\bMARK3\b|$))
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5CbMARK1%5Cb)(.*%3F)(%3F%3D(%3F%3A%5CbMARK2%5Cb%7C%5CbMARK3%5Cb%7C%24))&i=MARK1%20allthetext%20I%20need%20t0%20extr4ct%20i%24%20here%20unt.l%20I_will-find%20(MARK2%20%7C%20MARK3%20%7C%20ANYENDMARK)%0D%0A%0D%0AMARK1%20allthetext%20I%20need%20t0%20extr4ct%20i%24%20here%20unt.l%20I_will-find%20nothing%20else&o=s)

Note I am using singleline mode so that `.` could match a newline as well.

The `\b` is a word boundary that enables matching whole words. This, `\bMARK1\b` will not match `ANYMARK1`.

If you have `MARKn` at the end, you may use a bit different look-ahead: `(?<=\bMARK1\b)(.*?)(?=(?:\bMARK\d+\b|$))`. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5CbMARK1%5Cb)(.*%3F)(%3F%3C%3D%5CbMARK1%5Cb)(.*%3F)(%3F%3D(%3F%3A%5CbMARK%5Cd%2B%5Cb%7C%24))&i=MARK1%20allthetext%20I%20need%20t0%20extr4ct%20i%24%20here%20unt.l%20I_will-find%20MARK2345%0D%0A%0D%0AMARK1%20allthetext%20I%20need%20t0%20extr4ct%20i%24%20here%20unt.l%20I_will-find%20nothing%20else&o=s)

Now, the regex exaplanation comes:

- `(?<=\bMARK1\b)` - a look-behind that makes sure there is a whole word `MARK1` right before...
- `(.*?)` - any 0 or more (but as few as possible) characters (even including newline due to `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag used)
- `(?=(?:\bMARK2\b|\bMARK3\b|$))` - match the characters above only if they are followed with a whole word `MARK2` or `MARK3` or end of string.

Comment: I have added explanations now. I hope it is more or less clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Let's start from your second expression:

```
 (?<=(MARK1 ))([[:ascii:]]*)(?=(MARK2|MARK3|$))?
```

- Remove the question mark at the end:

  ```
   (?<=(MARK1 ))([[:ascii:]]*)(?=(MARK2|MARK3|$))
  ```

  You don't need it: The string is ended by either MARK2, MARK3 or the end of the line. That's not optional.
- Make the `*` of `[[:ascii:]]*` non-greedy by replacing it with `*?`:

  ```
   (?<=(MARK1 ))([[:ascii:]]*?)(?=(MARK2|MARK3|$))
  ```

  Otherwise, it will prefer the line end over MARK2 or MARK3, because it can do a longer match. `*?` will try to make the shortest match possible.
- You also probably want to add a space in front of MARK2 and MARK3, to avoid matching words ending with MARK2/3.

  ```
   (?<=(MARK1 ))([[:ascii:]]*?)(?=( MARK2| MARK3|$))
  ```

Comment: Just FYI: [Why can't I match POSIX Character Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9643797/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=MARK\d+).*?(?=MARK\d+|$)
```

You can use this.[See demo.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3dMARK%5cd%2b).*%3f(%3f%3dMARK%5cd%2b%7c%24)&i=MARK1+allthetext+I+need+t0+extr4ct+i%24+here+unt.l+I_will-find+(MARK2+%7c+MARK3+%7c+ANYENDMARK)%0d%0a%0d%0aor%0d%0a%0d%0aMARK1+allthetext+I+need+t0+extr4ct+i%24+here+unt.l+I_will-find+nothing+else)